# OCR Parsing get checkbox or Radiobutton value

Tags: api, parsing, text, ocr

I need to parse OCR image file and get all texts and checkbox values, How to get Checkbox or Radio Button value from OCR Parsing and Which one OCR Api is give corrected result extract from image.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check-box values can be read by specialized OMR software, not OCR.  OCR stands for Optical CHARACTER Recognition, and checkmark is not a character, but a compound object consisting of base checkmark object and some kind of mark on top of it.  OCR cannot provide a singe ASCII value for such combinaiton to represent a checkmark, thus a special OMR application needs to compare empty and marked value, and generate 1 or 0, true or false Boolean type value.  OMR stands for Optical Mark Recognition.

Comment: There are many tools.  I suggest ABBYY FlexiCapture to my cleints, which I have used myself.  http://www.wisetrend.com/abbyy-flexicapture/  (Disclaimer: I am a software reseller/integrator, including OMR software).  I would use it as a blackbox, not as API.  But I need to know much more about your needs if I were to make a recommendation.

Comment: I want to be parse a PDF document that is coming in form of images and contains multiple checkboxes and radio buttons also. So if any APIs are available for parsing or extract texts and values of checkboxes so it is very helpful for me. and i really very thanks for ur feedback.

Comment: If you can share a sample image, that will help.  Also, answer thees questions: 1) are all pages in exactly same format and fields are in the same place?  2) is PDF electronically generated, or scanned, or faxed or mobile picture? 3) do you need only checkmarks or also many need some text data?

Comment: 1) Yes, all pages same format and all fields also in the same place
2) PDF is generated by tool, and then it come in form of scanned copy and then want to parse it.
3) and all fields will be need to extract from it. and also attach a sample image

Comment: Ah, I see the image, that is an appraisal report. On the bottom of that image should be form version number, like "AICFULL" or "CRARF".  There will also be something like "Rev. 02/2008" to indicate specific format. Small variations in formatting in different revisions. Are you sure you have only one version and one variation? Challenges specific to this form: tight fields, 1000+ fields of data per form, also has character-based data (but you said you need check marks only). I used the same as I recommended - FlexiCapture for these forms. If you require any specific help, contact via e-mail.