# VB.NET - Image Analysis - Detecting marks in image

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, ocr

I want to know how, if it`s possible, to scan a PDF or image file and detects all marks in it to compile a result in a table or Excel file.

I`m working with a OMR (Optical Mark Recog.) with VB.NET, it can tell me if the mark is checked or not using pixels to specify where the mark is. The problem is that I have almost 70 marks in the form I want to analyse.

Is there a way to scan the file entirely and compile a result? I know it is possible but I need to know how...

Comment: Of course. And I can assure you that, without advanced knowledge of image processing algorithms, you should not attempt this without the help of third party libraries. Take a look at OpenCV (free, but aimed at C++) or Lead Tools or Matrox Imaging Library. You'll need a pattern match algorithm, perhaps NGC would do the trick.

Comment: If you are doing any kind of image detection I would steer away from VB/C#. OpenCV is a wonderful image library written in C++, Google also offer the Tesseract library which has a lot of wrappers for different languages.

Comment: @Adventure What you mean by NGC? And I found LeadTool on Google, seems good!

Comment: @Mathemats Unfortunately I don't know C++. Unable to understand its structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113111/ocr-parsing-get-checkbox-or-radiobutton-value

Comment: Normalized grayscale correlation, just one of MANY pattern match algorithms. There have been entire books written about which to use when and how they work. So your entering a technology that is both very deep and wide. Have fun.

Comment: Finally did it in C# using LeadTools OMR. I recommand it, it's easy to use and easy to understand!